# how to get the String from a view object returned by an onItemSelected() method

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

the onItemSelected() method is supposed to return a View as one of it's objects and in this case it is a textView that was verified by getting a description and hash of the object in Logcat, so view really is a TextView. the view returned by the method shown here

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

how can i get the String of text that is stored in that view?  for example if you do this,

```
 view.getText();
```

it is supposed to return the String that is stored in the textView, but does not work

however i have tried many different things like casting view to TextView to get the stored String from view and none of these things worked.  one of my failed attempts is like this here

```
  ((TextView) view).getText()
```

how can i get the String from the view that is returned by the onItemSelected callback method?

An ArrayList is loaded with Strings and is put into the adapter shown here,

```
  public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    ArrayList<String> objects;
    Context context;
    int textViewResourceId;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.objects = objects;
    }



  spinnerOne.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(StandardSelectionSettingsSmallTank.this, "id returned "+ Long.toString(id) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(StandardSelectionSettingsSmallTank.this, "view returned "+ ((TextView) view).getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });

        }
```

EDIT:   I just tried out the following code and it is doing exactly what I need done.  it gets the string that is stored in the current position of the spinner.   the string that I loaded earlier with the ArrayList.  this is working so i guess i will use this instead of using the View object that was returned by the onItemSelected method.

String selection = spinnerOne.getSelectedItem().toString();

i will use this unless anyone has an idea on how to do it the other way by using the view object

Comment: Are you trying to get the String selected from the spinner ?

Comment: yes, and .getSelectedItem() is working great for that purpose, i decided that i will use that, it is better than using view.

Comment: sorry about any confusion, sometimes the answer I am looking for is not the expected one.   if am still interested in figuring out how to get the String contents from the view object, but satisfied now that i don't need to do that.  i would rather understand how to do it both ways

Comment: Its alright. I got confused at first so deleted the answer ;). Glad that you solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check This one .

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() in place of  `((TextView) view).getText()`
```

Comment: Shobhit also has an excellent answer, however this answer gets the string from an object supplied by the onItemSelected callback method, so it is closer to the original question.  both answers are good and i will be using these methods in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
String selection=spinnerOne.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string from the object you set in adapter by the int position.

```
this.objects.get(position).getYourString();
```